# How to disable startup chime on MacBook Pro 5,2 (2009)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, startup

Following instructions for a [different problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/510939/1484565), I reset my MacBook's NVRAM with the result that now the previously disabled loud startup chime is back when powering on the system.

I followed the suggested solution to boot from a Mac OS X Install disk, open  Terminal and issued the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=%80
```

However after shutting down and rebooting the MacBook, the startup sound still remains.

I have also tried all of the below without any success

```
/usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=%01
/usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00
/usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=0
/usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=''
/usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=" "

/usr/sbin/nvram BootAudio=%00
/usr/sbin/nvram StartupMute=%01
```

I know that it's possible because the chime was muted before I reset the NVRAM.

I don't have Mac OS X installed on the MacBook so I cannot boot into that. The model is a MacBook Pro 5,2 from 2009 (Core 2 Duo). The `Boot ROM Version` is `MBP52.008E.B05` and the `SMC Version (system)` is `1.42f4`.

Comment: for what it's worth I noticed that whatever value I set SystemAudioVolume to, after powering off and on and reading it out again with `/usr/sbin/nvram -p`, it will always have a value of 0.

Comment: Any chance you can use the keyboard to mute the sound while booted from the Mac OS X Lion installation disk?

Comment: @DavidAnderson no, the volume keys don't do anything on the Mac OS X Lion setup screen and there is no volume bar or icon either.

Answer (score 1):

OK after spending countless hours on this, I finally figured it out. And in the end, I didn't even need Mac OS X for it.

Boot into Ubuntu, open a terminal window and issue the following commands:

1. `sudo rm /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SystemAudioVolume-7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82`
2. `printf "\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00" > ~/SystemAudioVolume-7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82`
3. `sudo cp ~/SystemAudioVolume-7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82 /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`

And yes, deleting and then creating and copying the var back to `/sys/efi/efivars` was the **ONLY** method that worked. Attempting to write the variable directly would give me a `permission denied` error, even with `sudo` and with its' immutable flag having been removed with `chattr -i`.

I'm guessing that you simply cannot modify the `SystemAudioVolume` var while booted from the Mac OS X installer disk. Whatever value I wrote into it with `/usr/sbin/nvram` from the installer's terminal would always be reset after a reboot.

Comment: Saved me mate. I did not have that `SystemAudio-Volume-...` efivar present at all, never thought about just creating it. But that worked.